# Can I have a vector in a structure that I access with a pointer and use STL capacity changing functions on it?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, stl

(Note that I am trying this on the LeetCode compiler because I am lazy and don't code on a separate IDE).
I have a structure with a vector (of pointers, but I do not believe it matters here). I made a pointer to this structure using malloc and then tried to perform a `struct->vector.push_back(...)` operation. Here is the code:

edit: As @joergbrech correctly pointed out, the code snippet doesn't help at all. Here's the whole thing.

```
class Solution {
public:
    struct Tnode {
        int val, n  ;
        Tnode *parent;
        vector<Tnode *> children;
    };
    
    vector<int> countSubTrees(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges, string labels) {
        unordered_map<int,Tnode*> mp;
        for (auto edge: edges) {
            if (!mp[edge[0]]) {
                Tnode *temp = (Tnode *) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
                temp->val = edge[0];
                mp[edge[0]] = temp;
            }
            if (mp[edge[1]]) {
                mp[edge[0]]->children.push_back(mp[edge[1]]);
                mp[edge[1]]->parent = mp[edge[0]];
            }
            if (!mp[edge[1]]) {
                Tnode *temp1 = (Tnode *) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
                temp1->val = edge[1];
                mp[edge[1]] = temp1;
                temp1->parent = mp[edge[0]];
                mp[edge[0]]->children.push_back(mp[edge[1]]);
            }
        }
        Tnode *root = mp[0];
        for (auto node: root->children)
            cout << node->val << ' ';
        return {};
    }
};
```

The compiler gave a deadly signal of incorrect memory read. The exact error is:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address (pc 0x0000002a2ae4 bp 0x000000000000 sp 0x7ffc0bf42dc0 T0)
==31==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==31==Hint: this fault was caused by a dereference of a high value address (see register values below).  Dissassemble the provided pc to learn which register was used.
    #6 0x7fcb3d5af0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==31==ABORTING
```

I surmised this is because when I do a malloc for the structure, it creates a "rigid" memory layout for the vars of the structure and performing a "push_back" would mess with that, hence causing the compiler to disallow the operation. Is that correct?

And as a sidenote, how would I make a structure with a dynamic sized data structure that could store a varying amount of children? I thought of a method where I make a pointer to an array of pointers to Tnode, but the implementation of that is pretty convoluted, so I thought it'd be better I confirm it even works. I couldn't really find anything on google that seemed particularly applicable either.

Comment: The code is using `malloc`, but does not **construct** a `Tnode` in that memory.  Instead starts using the Tnode unconstructed & uninitialized object before it's lifespan has started.  Probably should use `new` instead.

Comment: You are not allowed to use `malloc` for non-POD types.

Comment: Even better: Use smart pointers. Also: Your code is not reproducable: What is `edge`, `mp`, `parent`? There is no way to give you a better working code without knowing what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: You're learning C++ from a very miserable source if it suggests using `malloc`.

Comment: *I couldn't really find anything on google that seemed particularly applicable either.* -- The reason why you couldn't find anything is that you will not find any reputable C++ book or tutorial that shows using `malloc` to create objects.  [Please see this code sample using type_traits](https://godbolt.org/z/zEeG5j3oG)

Comment: As a side note, the "pc" is the Program Counter register, and the sanitizer (not the compiler) is suggesting that you disassemble the code at that address. It's not hilarious.

Comment: Bottom line is this -- C++ is not C.  Obviously you are using C techniques and practices in a C++ program.  All `malloc` does is give you a bunch of bytes -- it does *not* create objects.  Your code pretends it created the `TNode` object by casting `malloc` to a `TNode`.  All you did was fool the compiler into thinking that the `TNode` is a fully constructed object, when it isn't.  The only way to get that `malloc` to work, and to tell the C++ compiler that "Yes, I want that malloc to represent a TNode object" is to use `placement-new`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik -- I think it also could be a C programmers attempt of writing C++ code using C thinking, and getting bewildered that something that works in C fails to work for C++.  Look at the way the OP tries to explain what may be going on.  I've seen it a lot through the years.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Weird messaging there. I get that I'm wrong, but if I'm confused then where do I go to ask questions? I happen to not know any C++ programmers, and I'm not following any text books because of personal reasons I don' think anyone here needs to know. Where do you suggest I go with my confusions otherwise? And I only tried to explain myself because stack overflow implores I "show my working".

Comment: *and I'm not following any text books because of personal reasons* -- Well, C++ is one of the most complex computer languages out there.  Trying to learn C++ by using google or some other search engine is not the proper way to learn such a language.   Reputable, peer-reviewed, C++ books is the way to learn such a language, and following each chapter in those books.  Otherwise you will end up with strange errors, or worse, programs that seem to "work", but are riddled with undefined behavior.  What if your attempt "worked"?  You would never had known it was totally wrong.

Comment: You aren't using `n` nor `labels`, and I'm suspicious of `mp[0]`. How do you know there is a node numbered 0?

Comment: @Caleth The problem statement was such that they'd provide a collection of numerically differentiated nodes of an undirected tree, such that the root node is always assigned a 0. If you're interested it was yesterday's daily [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-nodes-in-the-sub-tree-with-the-same-label/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That what I think is happening

When you use the `malloc()` function, you are allocating space to store `struct Tnode`, but you are not doing any initialization of the `Tnode` members, in particular, you are not calling the constructor for `vector<Tnode *> child ;` That's causing the problem, if your structure only had basic types (int, float, char, pointers, etc.) you wouldn't have any problem, but with complex types like vector, you have to make sure you call the corresponding constructor. Having said that:

Try to change line:

`Tnode *temp1 = (Tnode *) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));`

by:

`Tnode *temp1 = new Tnode;`